# Is it possible to bind a metamask wallet account to my website's own accounts database?

Tags: metamask, wallets, nft

to be specific, we want a user that should first login to our website then after login be able to connect their wallet account. the question is, is it possible to create one account and bind the connected metamask wallet to that account only? since that login/authentication is for the sake of just having a two-factor security authentication for our website.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That can be done. After the user login to website, you can make user to connect to metamask, and store the connected metamask address against website login account.
But the problem is user may have/connect with multiple metamask account from one login.
You either have to ask user to connect with stored metamask address if he login or you have to store multiple metamask account(he is connecting with your website) against website login account based on your project need.